# Creating New Text Alignment Class to Seperate Posts and Sidebar Text Alignment Styles

Tags: css, text, alignment

I'm attempting to justify the post content text on my blog posts. I searched the style.css sheet for the #content section to change the paragraph text to "align:justify," However I was unable to find such a section. So I used firebug to inspect the page and found that the text properties were on a separate style sheet (text.css). So I opened that style sheet and changed the paragraph text alignment to justify. However, this changed the text on the entire page, including the sidebar text. So I inspected the sidebar with Firebug and found that the side bar text excerpt paragraph class isn't separated as it normally is. The post content text and sidebar excerpt text are all under the same class, so when I change it to justify, it changes them both. I'm guessing that I need to create a different class for the sidebar, can someone point me in the right direction? Thanks!

```
p {
padding: 5px 0;
margin: 0 0 5px;
text-align: left;
color:#666;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

most likely there is some sort of div for the side bar, if you don't want to use a specific class you could find the name of the sidebar div and use

```
#sidebar #content p{
   text-align:justify;
}
```

make sure you target the specific contents in the area you want changed

**edit:**

after viewing your source it seems like you should be able to target that `p` with

```
.srp-widget-container p{
   /*your styles here*/
 }
```

in the 960.css

Comment: if you post a link to your site i can try to be more specific

Comment: [Here's a link](http://www.popglitch.com) I'm still looking but I suspect the div for the sidebar is not in the style.css but must but in another style sheet.

Comment: Thanks a ton! I inspected with firebug and saw that the sidebar styling was indeed in a different css sheet "960" and not under the regular style.css as it usually is, so now I' can go in and change the styling! Thanks so much!